# "Index out of range error" while trying to read from a text file

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having some trouble with this code. I'm trying to read from a text file named "level1" and go line by line and add each line to an array using the .enumerated() function. But when I try to use the index to fill the array which when I print it starts from 0, it crashes and gives me the a error that it is accessing something out of range? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
var clueString = ""
var solutionString = ""
var letterBits = [String]()
var solutions = [String]()

var gameData: [String] = [String]()

func loadLevel() -> [String] {
    if let levelFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "level\(1)", ofType: "txt"){
        if let levelContents = try? String(contentsOfFile: levelFilePath) {
            var lines = levelContents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            lines = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: lines) as! [String]

            for (index, line) in lines.enumerated() {
                let parts = line.components(separatedBy: ": ")
                let answer = parts[0]
                let clue = parts[1]

                gameData[index].append(answer)
            }
        }
    }
    return gameData
}
```

Comment: Can you post your string?

Comment: On first glance, it seems to me that `gameData[index].append(answer)` is the culprit. Try `gameData.append(answer)`.

Comment: @DennisVennink Thanks man that worked! Can't believe I did not not think of that.

Comment: @DennisVennink You should post this as an answer so 47goon can accept it.

Comment: @KevinBallard Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a single element to the end of an [`Array`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array), you need to call [`append(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1538872-append) on the `Array` itself, not on the element it's supposed to go in to.

So in your code `gameData[index].append(answer)` needs to be changed to `gameData.append(answer)`.